# OTA using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, stm32, gsm, ota

I'm planning to do OTA (Over the Air) using Azure for my Simcom 4G GSM connected(UART) stm32. The communication between device and azure is via GSM only. I have searched many platform for solution mostly I heard device twin. But is it possible to do using the above spec and components. Or any other way to approach the OTA.
Note - For bin file storage I'm using blob storage.

So far I changed the json file in device twin using some reference
"desired":
{
"otaupdate": bloblink,
"version": 1.0
}
but from GSM side i don't know how to approach.

Comment: You're gonna need to react to the desired property update in code on your device. Best to use the SDK depending on the language you're using
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-device-twins#create-handlers

Comment: Yes I did understand and used get_twin.py as simulated device and ran the code I'm able to see the properties I changed, but I didn't understand how the OTA works here. Does the device twin fetch the bin file using only URL of the blob storage. What is the trigger here to know that all the bin content inside is fetched. For example if I'm having a webhost there I'm using upload firmware button. What is the process do I need to send the bin file.

Comment: depending on the OS you're using you will probably have to do the downloading & udpating yourself.

Comment: I'm using azure embedded C SDK. What I want to know is just call the get twin function and parse  the json only I'm able from device side. In azure side I just changed the json document as I mentioned. What else I need to do to send the bin from azure to device. No clue